# Style-wise <br> or padding/margin elements

Tags: css, html

These days with HTML5 and CSS3, is the use of `<br>` tags frowned upon when margin/padding can be used?

EDIT: This is in regards to spacing between div elements for my use case, but general best practice advise is also welcome.

Comment: I would generally suggest against using `<br>` tags.

Comment: If this isn't purely stylistic (e.g. separation of thoughts), you may be looking for `<hr>`, with custom styling (transparent, with `height` or `margin` for spacing).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are actually pretty well-defined rules around its usage, harking back to the days of [HTML 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt) when it was first introduced:

> The `<BR>` element specifies a line break between words (see 6, "Characters, Words, and Paragraphs"). For example:
>
> ```
> <P> Pease porridge hot<BR>
> Pease porridge cold<BR>
> Pease porridge in the pot<BR>
> Nine days old.
> ```

The `<br>` element itself was never intended to be used to control margin/padding. Although they introduced a presentational `clear` attribute to HTML 3.2 to handle things like floating images, it was soon deprecated in HTML 4 and XHTML 1 in favor of CSS. That was almost 15 years ago, so it's really nothing new.

In [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element), they've made it much clearer that `<br>` isn't intended for presentation or layout, with examples (and [the `clear` attribute is obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/br.html#br-constraints)):

> `br` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.
>
> > The following example is correct usage of the `br` element:
> >
> > ```
> > <p>P. Sherman<br>
> > 42 Wallaby Way<br>
> > Sydney</p>
> > ```
>
> `br` elements must not be used for separating thematic groups in a paragraph.
>
> > The following examples are non-conforming, as they abuse the `br` element:
> >
> > ```
> > <p><a ...>34 comments.</a><br>
> > <a ...>Add a comment.</a></p>
> > <p><label>Name: <input name="name"></label><br>
> > <label>Address: <input name="address"></label></p>
> > ```
> >
> > Here are alternatives to the above, which are correct:
> >
> > ```
> > <p><a ...>34 comments.</a></p>
> > <p><a ...>Add a comment.</a></p>
> >
> > <p><label>Name: <input name="name"></label></p>
> > <p><label>Address: <input name="address"></label></p>
> > ```

So using `<br>` in lieu of CSS margins for layout purposes has always been frowned upon, at least by the people who wrote the specifications.

Comment: The [specification for HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-br-element.html#the-br-element) is much more informative than the language reference: *br elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.*

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for the link. The HTML5 spec has been a navigational nightmare for me for some reason and I wasn't able to locate that section. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Using <br/> feels simpler and cleaner to me. Can anybody explain what downside it could cause?

Comment: @Jeff Zivkovic: br is known to be a pain to style with CSS. Even if you're not styling it directly, you can't control the amount of space created by a br without altering the line height of surrounding lines because a br *is* a unit line height in size. And as I mentioned in my answer, it's just flat-out semantically inappropriate - no matter how much simpler and cleaner it feels. It's like using tables for layout - it looks the part, but you don't actually have a table.

Comment: Ok. That does make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Depends whether you like working with line-height or margin/padding.

Comment: If you're using line-height to get the effect of a margin, you're probably doing it wrong.