# How many pixels in a <br>?

Tags: html, css

How many pixels does a `<br>` tag add? I know `<br>` height can be controlled via CSS `line-height` property. Do different browsers have same value or not?

Comment: Different browsers render things differently, so no, not every browser has the same value on `<br/>` tags.

Comment: Different browsers have different method for calculating the properties and pixels. Give it a try buddy!

Comment: i asked this because i found it same as i always use style reset sheet i never realized that its due to style reset sheet that make it look same... :)

Comment: Google sent me here.  Too bad there isn't a default answer given here, since I need to know how many before it does a page break in printing and do not want to mess with .css.  Good question.  Upvote.

Comment: I'm surprised. the Stackoverflow community is usually a lot more helpful than this. this is a valid question. there have already been some good answers here with the different browser responses.

Comment: Roughly 20 pixels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It adds as much as is resulted by how the browser calculates `line-height`.

Exactly how many "pixels" this is is up to the browser, since the browser is the one rendering the text after all. Why this should make any difference to you is not clear, unless you're using `<br>` for something it was not intended for, such as [arbitrary spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788503/style-wise-br-or-padding-margin-elements/12788551#12788551).

Comment: I wish I could upvote again for **"unless you're using `<br>` for something it was not intended for, such as arbitrary spacing."**

Answer (score 1):

The line break element adds the total calculated amount of pixels to the document as the  `line-height` does. Different browser have different algorithm and different methods to render the document for better viewing. That is why, `<br />` would have different result in different browsers.

To override this Browser way, you CSS reset. That would reset the browser properties.