# W3C compliance br tags in table

Tags: html, tags, w3c

I want the spacing in the UI to be exactly the same as the spacing in my modification. The original code was written as:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>stuff</td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
<td>stuff</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This code gives a w3c error and is incorrect. I modified this code to:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>stuff</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none;"><td><br/></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>stuff</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This code is w3c compliant but I noticed that the spacing in the modification is completely different than the original code, which is not a desired result.

Does anyone know why this occurs and/or a way to fix this issue?

Comment: why are you using a break between table rows?

Comment: CSS (height) to get the spacing correct and forget about the <br/>.

Also, your display:none is going to hide the whole row, so take that out.

Comment: I wasn't the one who put the break between the table rows, but I still need to fix this code.

Comment: Of course the spacing is different. You are hiding the row

Comment: You could use `border-spacing` instead - http://jsfiddle.net/9yoLghed/

Comment: So it would be <tr style="border-spacing: 0 10px;"><td></td></tr>? It's 10px for each <br/> tag?

Comment: Check this out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466071/how-many-pixels-in-a-br I looked up how many pixels a <br/> tag has and it's different depending on the browser. I don't know if border-spacing will help solve this issue?

Comment: What do you think @MaryMelody

Comment: The original code is invalid, so it has no defined rendering. Defining your *goal* in terms of the undefined effect of such markup is not constructive. Define what you want and show what you have tried to achieve that, and exactly how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element). It must only be used for meaningful line breaks that are part of the content (e.g., [in addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669) or [in poems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753902/1591669)).

You should use CSS instead.

You might want to use your browser’s developer tools to inspect the applied CSS (probably coming from browser’s default stylesheets if there is no author-styling for the `br` element) of the original code, and try to reimplement it for the new code (targeting existing/valid elements).